How to create a regex for a 6-digit number where the last 3 digits are one more than the first 3 digits?
My task is to match special numbers based on customer requirements.
Examples of numbers I already match include:

Quadruple digits: 1111, 2222, ...

Sequential numbers: 123456, 234567, ...

Palindromic numbers: 123321, 234432, ...


I use regex to find these numbers (from a pre-generated list of 4-6 digit numbers).
Now, I'm having difficulty to match a specific pattern that consists of 6-digit numbers whose 3-digit parts differ by one: xyz (xyz+1), for example, 100101, 101102, ..., 199200, ...
The regex documentation I have referred to is https://www.rexegg.com/regex-tricks.php

Please Post your solution as an actual answer (don't integrate it via edit into the question).

Regular expressions don't do arithmetic.  You'd have to have an expression that lists lots of different combinations - I think there'd have to be 29 separate parts to it, and it would be so complex as to be unmaintainable.  I suggest you search for a different solution.

I Don't think Regex is a good solution for this use case

Does solution have to use only regex? If not then I would suggest iterating over any 6 digit number (you can use regex for that), splitting it into start/end parts and simply check if (start+1==end). You can also decide how to handle number like 999000, if you want to accept it or not.

I came up with this rather short solution:
^(?:(?=(\d)..\1(?!0*$)|(?:0..1|1..2|2..3|3..4|4..5|5..6|6..7|7..8|8..9|9..0)0*$)\d){3}\d{3}$

What it does is to make sure every three digits are the same (\d)..\1, if not, it must be the increasing pattern (1..2, 2..3, etc.), which either be the 3rd/6th digit, or any digits that followed by a bunch of 0s (it means that digit and all digits after it got carried from 9 to 0).
See test cases

BTW: what would you think how the question could be improved?

@Wolf Yes, the anchors are needed here, otherwise it will match numbers that have more than 6 digits 0012013 etc. It also make it perform better with fewer attempts.

Concerning the anchors: Isn't this too restrictive? So we only match strings that entirely consist of 6-digit numbers.

But generally it really depends on are you trying to verify a whole string or trying to find a substring from a longer string. For your question, it is clear enough but you generally get downvoted if people think a non-regex solution for your question is easier under the regex tag. I guess that's how it works here. But I did upvote, since it's a very interesting problem to solve using regex, althought it might not be practical

You could also utilize atomic groups or possessive quantifiers to further boost the performance, although you only had one group it won't change that much. But be aware abusing it could cause false negatives

by the way, in java they are called non-capturing groups

Sorry for the delayed reply. Your answer was really helpful to me. Thank you very much for that.

We are searching for six-digit patterns d₅d₄d₃d₂d₁d₀ that also match
int(d₅d₄d₃) + 1 == int(d₂d₁d₀)

At first, this looks like an arithmetic problem.
But when we consider the limited amount (999) of such patterns, it seems also reachable to a lexical approach:
In 900 of the cases, the first two digits in each 3-digit part are identical because there is no carry in addition:
d5 == d2 && 
d4 == d1 && 
d3+1 == d0

In 90 of the remaining cases, the first digit in each 3-digit part is identical because there is a double carry in addition:
d5 == d2 && 
d4+1 == d1 && 
d3 == 9 && 
d0 == 0

The remaining 9 cases show a double carry.
d5+1 == d2 && 
d4 == 9 && 
d3 == 9 && 
d1 == 0 && 
d0 == 0

These last 9 cases will be added literally.
It's quite hard to write such a regex by hand without errors. I decided to it via copy & paste in Notepad++ (which is capable of PCRE).
It's also hard to read, so I show it Perl syntax using the /x modifier so that most whitespace is ignored and we can also add comments:
/
# match 9 double-carry (literal) cases:
099100|199200|299300|399400|499500|599600|699700|799800|899900|

# match 90 single-carry cases:
(?<d09>\d)09\k<d09>10|
(?<d19>\d)19\k<d19>20|
(?<d29>\d)29\k<d29>30|
(?<d39>\d)39\k<d39>40|
(?<d49>\d)49\k<d49>50|
(?<d59>\d)59\k<d59>60|
(?<d69>\d)69\k<d69>70|
(?<d79>\d)79\k<d79>80|
(?<d89>\d)89\k<d89>90|

# match 900 non-carry cases:
(?<dd01>\d{2})0\k<dd01>1|
(?<dd12>\d{2})1\k<dd12>2|
(?<dd23>\d{2})2\k<dd23>3|
(?<dd34>\d{2})3\k<dd34>4|
(?<dd45>\d{2})4\k<dd45>5|
(?<dd56>\d{2})5\k<dd56>6|
(?<dd67>\d{2})6\k<dd67>7|
(?<dd78>\d{2})7\k<dd78>8|
(?<dd89>\d{2})8\k<dd89>9

/x

It also uses named capture groups, because when I started it, I had to switch positions of alternating parts more than once.
Porting this regex to Java seems rather easy. But it's unclear to me if such a regex solution will come at a reasonable performance level.  So I'd expect we have to do further research here.
Edit #1:
Fixed regex. Before, there were two copy-paste errors in group names that lead to only 889 instead of 999 matches. So again, regexes like this are really hard to write by hand. ;-)

Please explain: Why the downvote?

This doesn't sound like an academic exercise so I would not recommend a pure regex approach. It also benefits you or whoever maintains the code to be able easily modify it if the customer changes their requirements.
This uses a hybrid approach that includes a regex.  The regex is used to extract only six digit integers and ignores anything else. Using division and remainder operators to verify the match it filters out matches that don't fit the criteria.

The pattern excludes anything other than 6 digits.
the matching string is grabbed from the match results
and then parsed into an integer where the check can be made.
It is formatted to a string (to preserve leading 0's) and entered into a list.

String s = "1010 199200 202203 403403 209211 20110111 001002 2030220303";

List<String> results = Pattern.compile("(?<!\\d)(\\d{6})(?!\\d)")
        .matcher(s).results().mapToInt(mr->Integer.parseInt(mr.group()))
        .filter(i->i/1000 + 1 == i%1000)
        .mapToObj("%06d"::formatted)
        .toList();

results.forEach(System.out::println);


prints
199200
202203
001002

The above uses a stream to collect the information and place it in a list.  However, it could also be employed as a simple match expression.
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("(?<!\\d)(\\d{6})(?!\\d)").matcher(s);

while (m.find()) {
    int v = Integer.parseInt(m.group());
    if (v / 1000 + 1 == v % 1000) {
        System.out.printf("Match!! %06d%n", v);
    }
}

prints
Match!! 199200
Match!! 202203
Match!! 001002


Did you measure? I'd expect this to be faster than all pure-regex approaches we have so far.

A regex pattern alone cannot directly compare numeric values with mathematical conditions. It requires extra logic outside of just a regex match.
